# What does it means when someone cannot find a specific webpage by site: in Google?

Tags: google-search, google-index

What does it means when someone cannot find a specific webpage by `site:` in Google?

The page was indexed by Google earlier but cannot be found even with `site:` operator. What will that mean?

Answer (score 1):

It probably means the page is no longer indexed. This could be due to penalties applied since the page was first indexed. Google is constantly applying quality control updates to their algorithm (commonly known as Panda and Penguin) which can have a negative impact on pages it considers low quality.

Comment: So how to overcome, I do not see any manual action taken in webmaster tool, How to know - what caused the Google Penalty anyway...... Please help me!

Comment: There's no way for us to know why this happened. But you should read up on the Panda and Penguin updates and see what they targeted. Then if you think your site did any of those things then remove/fix it. Then you have to wait for the next update to see if it worked.